# SQL Server Agent available on Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, sql-server-agent

I would like to delete records from an database table on Azure when the table reaches a certain size.

I would normally do this by scheduling a stored procedure job using SQL Server Agent.

Is the SQL Server Agent available on databases held on Azure?

Should I use an alternative approach?

Comment: Use Azure WebJobs to execute the logic you need (calling a sproc in the database?): http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-get-started/

Answer (score 2):

If you run SQL Server in a Virtual Machine (or a cluster of Virtual Machines), you'll have all available features at your disposal.

If you are using Azure SQL Database *service*, there are some differences in terms of features offered. With SQL Database, SQL Server Agent is not available. If use of SQL Server Agent is a necessity, you'll need to run SQL Server in a VM.

The list of limitations is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee336281.aspx).